# React Native Circular Slider?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've tried to look through several libraries of React Native circular sliders, however none of them work as intended. All of them suffer the same bug where they randomly change values as you slide. A example would be:

[image]

What I am looking for, is a circular slider with it's value in the middle of the slider, very much so like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance

**Edit:** I've added a test repo if you want to play around with it. I've tried my best, but this is the best I could do

https://github.com/2joocy/SliderTest

**The code was taken from here:**

https://github.com/steveliles/react-native-circular-slider-example

Comment: How about https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-slider or https://github.com/raymondchooi/react-native-circle-slider

Comment: The last one you mentioned worked perfectly without the bugs I mentioned. Could you attach it as a post and I'll mark it as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't worked with circle slider yet. But I tried to search and there are 2 repos. Maybe that is what you need.

https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-slider

https://github.com/raymondchooi/react-native-circle-slider

Good luck!

Comment: For those interested in implementing their own sliders, only the last one from raymondchooi works. The one made from bgryszko is old and no longer supported. You can make it work, however it suffers from the same stuttering as in the GIF that I have attached to the post. Raymonds works without stuttering and is easilly modifiable.

Comment: @WilliamPfaffe raymondchooi is very old also. After finished, please post your circle slide repo on GitHub for the new circle slide. Very appreciated. ^^.

Comment: working on bugfixing it atm. Adding some more features as we speak. You can download it at https://github.com/2joocy/react-native-circular-slider

Comment: Hi @WilliamPfaffe... This https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circle-slider doesn't work with RN 56 out of the box unfortunately. And the 2joocy repo is not the same code as is on npm. Where can I find the repo for that? Cheers.

Comment: is it possible to make this as a volume controller?

Comment: @BMX I think yes, but you have to custom something

Comment: @tuledev would you mind suggesting me how to do that?

Comment: @BMX First, read and understand what the repo can do, try with it first. If it doesn't fit with your needs, you can fork the repo and then edit the source code